# What are all the audio types available in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, audio

What are the audio types with which we can record and play back in iPhone? Is any majorly used audio types missed by them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most widely used audio formats can be used, including:

**MPEG, WAVE, CAFF, AIFF**

Formats that cannot be used (without an external library) are:

**FLAC (unfortunately), OGG-Vorbis**

CAFF is the format Apple uses for sound recording in the iOS SDK.

Comment: @Krishnan: QuickTime supports AMR audio, but I am not sure it will natively play on an iOS device. I will try it out today.